Deleted SPWFM certificate has crashed SPWFM and ServiceBus - Unable to uninstall or generate new SSL cert
We have a single-server SharePoint Farm with SPWFM also installed on the same server.
Our self-signed certificates used for SPWFM expired, and when we tried to renew them ourselves we're getting the following error:

Auto-generation of certificate is not supported if user has specified
certificate thumbprints.

We opened a ticket with Microsoft Pro Support, and they asked us to run the following SQL statements on the WFManagement and SBManagement databases:
-- Run against WFManagement
update [Store].[ClusterConfig] set Value = 'True' where Name = 'IsOutboundCertificateGenerated'
update [Store].[ClusterConfig] set Value = 'True' where Name = 'ServiceSSLAutoGenerated'
update [Store].[ServiceConfig] set Value = 'True' where Name= 'IsEncryptionCertifacteGenerated'

-- Run against SBManagement
update [Store].[ClusterConfig] set Value = 'True' where Name = 'IsClusterCertificateGenerated' 
update [Store].[ClusterConfig] set Value = 'True' where Name = 'ServiceSSLAutoGenerated'
update [Store].[ServiceConfig] set Value = 'True' where Name = 'IsEncryptionCertificateGenerated'

After doing so, we were able to generate new self-signed SSL certificates for SPWFM. We got to the steps where we left the SPWFM farm, and while attempting to rejoin we received an error in the SPWFM configuration tool due to our service namespace having a non-standard name.
While Microsoft Support was troubleshooting the above-mentioned error, the technician asked us to delete the newly-generated SSL certificates from IIS, which we reluctantly did. This appears to have now made things worse, unfortunately. We can no longer open the SPWFM configuration tool. When we do, it immediately crashes with the following error in Windows Event logs:

We also tried uninstalling SPWFM from the server, but when we try to we're getting the following error:

Because we cannot open the SPWFM Configuration tool, we cannot run the "Leave from Farm" action. Also, when we try to use Remove-SBHost PowerShell command we are getting the following error message in PowerShell:

We now appear to be in a catch-22 situation. We cannot uninstall SPWFM from the server, and we also cannot open the configuration tool to leave the farm. And, as a result of all of this, we cannot run any workflows in SharePoint.
Anyone have an idea of what options are available to recover from our issue? We've lost the ability to run workflows in SharePoint. We need to restore this functionality as soon as possible.

Well, Microsoft Support was not much help, unfortunately. To fix this I ended up abandoning the SPWFM Farm installed on the SharePoint server (i.e. disabling all of the relevant services). I created a new, single-node SPWFM farm, installed on a separate server, then pointed SharePoint over to use that farm instead. See the instructions below, and amend according to your needs:
https://joshroark.com/clean-up-and-re-register-with-spwfm/
Since the workflow definitions are stored in the SharePoint Content Database, we did not lose them, nor did we lose their associations with the various content types, library/lists, in SharePoint. We did, however, need to use SharePoint Designer to open each site with a workflow defined, then republish the workflow so that it registered with the new SPWFM farm. They would not trigger, otherwise.
We also lost all of the running workflow instances and their history, although that wasn't a big deal for our farm since all of our workflows are short-duration workflows according to our company policies.
